# Getting concrete5 integer attribute value for comparison

Tags: php, concrete5

I am using a system (concrete5) to edit some php in place.  I am trying the following:

```
use Concrete\Core\User\UserInfo;
$ui = UserInfo::getByID(3);
$answer = $ui->getAttribute('Q1');
if ($answer >= 5)
    print "True";
```

When I insert a check on `$answer` by inserting `print $answer`, it returns 6 (this is attribute data held on the user).  However, the `if` does not evaluate to true.  And ideas why?  Must I typeset the output or something?

Edit:
I typecast to int with the same result.

Comment: Try to cast your `(int) $answer` and add else statement to make sure that the comparison is working

Comment: Must be something else https://3v4l.org/dcmn0 try `var_dump($answer);`

Comment: var_dump gave me An unexpected error occurred.
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65028096 bytes)

Comment: PHP is loosely typed, string "6" will be converted to 6. You're obviously returning something that isn't valid.

Comment: What version of Concrete5 is OP using and what version of PHP?  Also, need to see more code, i.e. the attribute 'Q1' and is its value hard-coded or dynamically set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selected answer is not the proper approach.

Use `$ui->getAttribute('Q1','display')`.

```
use Concrete\Core\User\UserInfo;
$ui = UserInfo::getByID(3);
$answer = $ui->getAttribute('Q1','display');
if ($answer >= 5)
print "True";
```

See concrete5 documentation to know more about attributes-
https://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/attributes/attribute-value-objects-and-output-formatting

Comment: I did test this and it worked.  Can you list the source?  If so, I will mark this as the right answer for people in future.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what did you mean by list the source. If you're looking for the reference, you may look at this code https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/blob/1180d447bcd2aa5e8ab9eedbcf28e339f8d211a6/concrete/src/Attribute/ObjectTrait.php#L24-L30

Comment: I had meant something in documentation. As I can see this is a 'more correct' answer, I will mark it as the answer for others who hit this issue.

Comment: I've added the documentation page reference.

Answer (score 1):

If $answer is an object, with the __toString function defined, then all that is described there can happen. Try something like this:

```
use Concrete\Core\User\UserInfo;
$ui = UserInfo::getByID(3);
$answer = $ui->getAttribute('Q1');
$answer = $answer.'';
if ($answer >= '5')
    print "True";
```

Comment: This seems to have worked.  I will apply it to every other instance, thanks!

Comment: I ended up using `$answer = $ui->getAttribute('Q1').'';`

Comment: There is a little error in my code: <code>if ($answer >= '5')</code> should be if ($answer >= 5) to force php to compare as integers, not as strings.